# Finding tag value with another tag in Beautiful soup

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the value (Restaurant name) from a **span** tag within an **a** tag.

There are a lot of a tags and span tags. I used this code to get here:

```
soup.find_all("a", "biz-name js-analytics-click")

<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" data- 
hovercard-id="hN6KsYexY7_4VPAw0mHtMA" href="/biz/szechuan-restaurant- 
charlottesville?osq=chinese"><span>Szechuan Restaurant</span></a>
```

So basically I don't know how to find a value of a **span** tag, which is located in an **a** tag with specific class = "biz-name js-analytics-click"

Answer (score 0):

Try `span.text`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" data- 
hovercard-id="hN6KsYexY7_4VPAw0mHtMA" href="/biz/szechuan-restaurant- 
charlottesville?osq=chinese"><span>Szechuan Restaurant</span></a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
for tag in soup.find_all("a", "biz-name js-analytics-click"):
    print(tag.span.text)
```

*or if*  `"biz-name js-analytics-click"` *is unique then*

```
print( soup.find("a", "biz-name js-analytics-click").span.text )
```

**Output:**

```
Szechuan Restaurant
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to make code complicated, BeautifulSoup supports CSS selectors in form of methods `select()` and `select_one()` ([docs here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)).

If you want to find `<span>` tag inside `<a>` tag with classes `biz-name` and `js-analytics-click`, use selector `'a.biz-name.js-analytics-click span'`:

```
data = """<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" data-
hovercard-id="hN6KsYexY7_4VPAw0mHtMA" href="/biz/szechuan-restaurant-
charlottesville?osq=chinese"><span>Szechuan Restaurant</span></a>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('a.biz-name.js-analytics-click span').text)
```

Outputs:

```
Szechuan Restaurant
```